# A DreamFace widget corresponds to which Angular component?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, module, widget

We can define controllers in a DreamFace widget, I'd like to know to which Angular component a widget refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a DreamFace widget refers to an Angular module. All controllers, functions, etc. defined in the source/script part of the widget will depend on its relative module. When you deploy the application, these modules are declared in the app, if at least one screen of the application uses the widget.